# How to intercept request from QWebEngineView and serving them directely from the application?

Tags: qt, qwebengineview, pyq

Is there a way with `QWebEngineView` to intercept an http request, and to serve it server-less from the app ?

I heard about `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` and `acceptNavigationRequest()`, but they provide only inspection on requests, and redirection for get... But I would like to make the http response from the Qt app.

(I added pyqt in the tags because I would use it from python, but a c++ answer is acceptable too)

Answer (score 1):

The [qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineurlrequestinfo.html#redirect) says the redirection is only for GET request. However, when trying it out (PyQt6==6.4.0) we found out that this is actually not true. If you redirect a POST request in the WebEngine to a local webserver listening on localhost, you will actually receive the request including the payload.

Perhaps this is because Webkit doesn't include the payload for redirect and  Chromium does? (I couldn't find docs stating the difference.)

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor


class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        method = info.requestMethod()
        if method == "POST":
            if info.requestUrl().url() == "https://my-url-to-something":
                info.redirect(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000"))
```